# iPhone SDK symbol not found, defined in .mm file

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4

I'm trying to build an objective c++ class, which compiles fine until someone tries to use the class. I want open  a viewController  with modal view Controller but the compiler gives me this warning :

> ```
> MainView.mm: warning: Semantic Issue: Method
> ```
>
> '-presentModalViewController:animated:' not found (return type defaults to
>   'id')

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainView : UIView <UIApplicationDelegate> {



    UIWindow *window;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

- (IBAction)showInfo;
```

.mm :

```
    #import "Calendar.h"

@implementation MainView
@synthesize window , day ,year ,myDate ,eventsLabel , bg;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self == [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

    }
    return self;
}



    - (IBAction)showCal {

        Calendar *controller = [[Calendar alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        [MainView presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

        [controller release];
    }
```

and application crashes ! so what can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: You should show the code that uses `-presentModalViewController:animated:`.  My guess would be that you are trying to invoke that method on an object of the wrong class.

Comment: Post the code used for Presenting ModelViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-presentModalViewController:animated:` is a method of the `UIViewController` class.

Is `self` in your code a view controller?  Or is it just a view?

Comment: No its just a View : `@interface MainView : UIView <UIApplicationDelegate>`

Comment: Then that's your problem. You need to call that method from MainView's controller, not the view.  `-showInfo:` should probably be a method of the controller, rather than of the view.  Views should generally just draw themselves and lay out subviews; any "real work" should be in the controller.

Comment: so i would be grateful if you show me how .sorry I am new to iPhone SDK

Comment: It would be hard to show you without looking at all of your code, but I'm guessing that somewhere you have a subclass of `UIViewController` associated with your view.  The `-showInfo` method should be a member of that class.  Then, in Interface Builder where you have the connection from whatever triggers the action to `-showInfo:`, change that connection so that it points to the controller (which is probably the File's Owner object) rather than to the view.